# How to validate data received via the Telegram's Web App

Tags: python, encryption, hash, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to validate WebApp data but the result is not what I wanted.

[Telegram documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#validating-data-received-via-the-web-app):

```
data_check_string = ...
secret_key = HMAC_SHA256(<bot_token>, "WebAppData")
if (hex(HMAC_SHA256(data_check_string, secret_key)) == hash) {
    // data is from Telegram
}
```

MyCode:

```
BOT_TOKEN = '5139539316:AAGVhDje2A3mB9yA_7l8-TV8xikC7KcudNk'

data_check_string = 'query_id=AAGcqlFKAAAAAJyqUUp6-Y62&user=%7B%22id%22%3A1246866076%2C%22first_name%22%3A%22Dante%22%2C%22last_name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22username%22%3A%22S_User%22%2C%22language_code%22%3A%22en%22%7D&auth_date=1651689536&hash=de7f6b26aadbd667a36d76d91969ecf6ffec70ffaa40b3e98d20555e2406bfbb'
data_check_arr = data_check_string.split('&')
needle = 'hash='
hash_item = ''
telegram_hash = ''
for item in data_check_arr:
    if item[0:len(needle)] == needle:
        telegram_hash = item[len(needle):]
        hash_item = item
data_check_arr.remove(hash_item)
data_check_arr.sort()
data_check_string = "\n".join(data_check_arr)
secret_key = hmac.new("WebAppData".encode(), BOT_TOKEN.encode(),  hashlib.sha256).digest()
calculated_hash = hmac.new(data_check_string.encode(), secret_key, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

print(calculated_hash == telegram_hash) # print False
```

I'm trying to validate webapp data in python, but my code didn't give the intended result.
the hash which my code gives me is different from the telegram's one.

**UPDATE**: valid data added, and bot-token has been changed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unquote data_check_string

```
from urllib.parse import unquote 
data_check_string = unquote('query_id=AAGcqlFKAAAAAJyqUUp6-Y62&user=%7B%22id%22%3A1246866076%2C%22first_name%22%3A%22Dante%22%2C%22last_name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22username%22%3A%22S_User%22%2C%22language_code%22%3A%22en%22%7D&auth_date=1651689536&hash=de7f6b26aadbd667a36d76d91969ecf6ffec70ffaa40b3e98d20555e2406bfbb')
```

And swap the arguments

```
calculated_hash = hmac.new(secret_key, data_check_string.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the for-loops with a couple of lines (already incorporates [kurdyukovpv's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72391757/14132412) to unquote the query string):

```
data_check_string = sorted([ chunk.split("=") for chunk in unquote(data_check_string).split("&") 
        if chunk[:len("hash=")]!="hash="],
        key=lambda x: x[0])
data_check_string = "\n".join([f"{rec[0]}={rec[1]}" for rec in data_check_string])
```

EDIT: Figured I might as well just post the entire working function I got out of this thread ) :

```
import hmac
import hashlib
from urllib.parse import unquote

def validate(hash_str, init_data, token, c_str="WebAppData"):
    """
    Validates the data received from the Telegram web app, using the
    method documented here: 
    https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#validating-data-received-via-the-web-app

    hash_str - the has string passed by the webapp
    init_data - the query string passed by the webapp
    token - Telegram bot's token
    c_str - constant string (default = "WebAppData")
    """

    init_data = sorted([ chunk.split("=") 
          for chunk in unquote(init_data).split("&") 
            if chunk[:len("hash=")]!="hash="],
        key=lambda x: x[0])
    init_data = "\n".join([f"{rec[0]}={rec[1]}" for rec in init_data])

    secret_key = hmac.new(c_str.encode(), token.encode(),
        hashlib.sha256 ).digest()
    data_check = hmac.new( secret_key, init_data.encode(),
        hashlib.sha256)

    return data_check.hexdigest() == hash_str
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import hmac
import hashlib
from urllib.parse import unquote

def validate(hash_str, init_data, token, c_str="WebAppData"):
    """
    Validates the data received from the Telegram web app, using the
    method documented here: 
    https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#validating-data-received-via-the-web-app

    hash_str - the has string passed by the webapp
    init_data - the query string passed by the webapp
    token - Telegram bot's token
    c_str - constant string (default = "WebAppData")
    """

    init_data = sorted([ chunk.split("=") 
          for chunk in unquote(init_data).split("&") 
            if chunk[:len("hash=")]!="hash="],
        key=lambda x: x[0])
    init_data = "\n".join([f"{rec[0]}={rec[1]}" for rec in init_data])

    secret_key = hmac.new(c_str.encode(), token.encode(),
        hashlib.sha256 ).digest()
    data_check = hmac.new( secret_key, init_data.encode(),
        hashlib.sha256)

    return data_check.hexdigest() == hash_str


it is working BUT there is a problem when first_name contains &

RESOLIVNG IS

init_data = sorted([chunk.split("=") for chunk in init_data.split("&") if chunk[:len("hash=")] != "hash="], key=lambda x: x[0])
    init_data = "\n".join([f"{rec[0]}={unquote(rec[1])}" for rec in init_data])
    secret_key = hmac.new(c_str.encode(), token.encode(), hashlib.sha256).digest()
    data_check = hmac.new(secret_key, init_data.encode(), hashlib.sha256)
    return data_check.hexdigest() == hash_str

do {unquote(rec[1]) after sorting`enter code here`
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).